# How to iterate through node while there is a relationship

Tags: while-loop, neo4j, cypher

I have nodes that are structured like folder, subfolder and files. Any folder can have a relationship with a subfolder, which can have a relationship with another subfolder, which can have a relationship with files. I'd like to iterate through every folder to find every subfolder and files inside a given folder.

[image: The structure looks like that]

In one query, I'd like to be able to get every file that is inside a folder or in his subfolders. I can't find any way to do it with Cypher. I saw FOREACH and UNWIND but I don't think it helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have labelled the nodes accordingly as Folder and File, the following query will fetch all the files belonging to the starting folder, directly or through a chain of one or more sub-folders:

```
MATCH(ParentFolder:Folder)-[*]->(childFile:File)
WHERE ParentFolder.name='Folder1'
RETURN childFile
```

If you haven't used Labels (highly recommend using them), you can look for all the paths starting with the specified folder and find all the last nodes in that path.

```
MATCH(ParentFolder)-[*]->(childFile)
WHERE ParentFolder.name='Folder1' AND NOT (childFile)-->()
RETURN childFile
```

The second query will fetch all the terminal nodes, even if they are folders. You would have to use labels or add filters in the where clause to ensure only files are fetched for childFile.

Both versions of the query work based on [varying length paths](https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/training-intro-40/05-working-with-patterns-in-queries/#_specifying_varying_length_paths). The wild character(*) retrieves all paths of any length starting from ParentFolder.

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know that [*] syntaxe, that's what i needed.